# Current status of support for parallell migration on a MariaDB Galera cluster

Tags: mysql, mariadb, flyway, galera

The Flyway docs [state](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/learnmore/faq.html#parallel) that

> Flyway uses the locking technology of your database to coordinate multiple nodes. This ensures that even if multiple instances of your application attempt to migrate the database at the same time, it still works. Cluster configurations are fully supported.

When migrating on a MariaDB Galera cluster on Flyway versions > 6 (and maybe earlier, haven't checked), `MySQLConnection` or `MySQLNamedLockTemplate` is used to coordinate locks between multiple nodes migrating simultaneously. `MySQLConnection`/`MySQLNamedLockTemplate` implement locking through [`get_lock()`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/get_lock/)

However, `get_lock()` is [not supported in Galera](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-galera-cluster-known-limitations/):

> Unsupported explicit locking include [...] GET_LOCK(), [...]

And indeed, when migrating in parallel on 2 nodes on our Galera cluster we frequently see errors because both nodes try to migrate at the same time (even in [grouped mode](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/parameters/group)).

It looks like [this was a known issue in 2018](https://www.meshcloud.io/2018/05/18/migrating-a-galera-cluster-with-flywaydb/). What is the current status of the issue? Is there a plan for supporting parallel migration on Galera clusters in the Flyway project, or is there some external project that implements this?

Comment: What is the goal of "parallel migration"?

Comment: The goal is to be able to start applications that include flyway migrations on multiple nodes, without worrying the they will interfere with each other during the migration phase.

Comment: `GET_LOCK` is [no longer executed](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/pull/3674) by Flyway on 18 May 2023. Probably need to raise the exact issue with Flyway.

Answer (score 1):

The issue has been fixed in Flyway version 9.19.1 see [release notes](https://documentation.red-gate.com/fd/release-notes-for-flyway-engine-179732572.html)

This was the [pull request](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/pull/3674) that fixed the issue.